# How to set permission for log file of log4j programmatically?

Tags: java, linux, macos, log4j

If my application is run by root user, creating log file by root. So, if the app is run by another users, display 'permission denied'.

There are the logs in `/opt/myapp/logs/` .

I want to set permission for log file of log4j programmatically (May be using log4j configuration) (All user should write the log file. To permit as chmod `766`). Is it possible?

Comment: Why not change the permissions of the directory, where the log is written ?

Comment: Don't have *nix systems have a special place to put logs into?

Comment: My app logs are in /opt/myapp/logs/

Answer (score 0):

Writing logs to single folder will require to manually set log file name and change log folder permissions.

If you need to run your application from many users you will likely should use user home (or sub folder) to write logs.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Filesystem Hierarchy Standard, logs must be put in `/var/log`. You can avoid clutter this folder by creating a `/var/log/myapp` folder, where you'll put your logs. Ensure the folder and its contents are chmod 666, or better, 766.

This is the standard used by Apache, for example.